# Jump to last row in Column A, with blank rows between data and land in Column A

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

This script works and jumps from a user menu on tool bar to last row but since columns are A to Z, it always lands on the last row and in Column Z and I just navigate to the left to Column A

Is there a simple way to make it land in Column A instead of Z ?

```
function CountColA(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = data.length-1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
    if (data[i][0] != null && data[i][0] != ''){
      return i+1 ;
    }
  }
}
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Go To End', functionName: 'goToEnd'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('My Menu', menuItems);
}
function goToEnd() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
  // Browser.msgBox('values: ' + lastRow + '-' + lastColumn);
  sheet.setCurrentCell(lastCell);
  //sheet.setCurrentCell(lastRow);// <-- This of course does not work but would be preferred;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1);
```